# Irssi: Pressiing CTRL + 2 makes further keyboard input impossible

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, irssi

I'm using Irssi in a terminal window.

If I accidentally press CTRL + 2 or any number key above 1, I can no longer enter text into the Irssi window. I need to close the terminal window, killing Irssi, and restart.

Has anyone come across this? Why does Ctrl + a number freeze Irssi input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in a library (GLib) installed on your Ubuntu. Looks like they are already working on a fix here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/irssi/+bug/1882401